# Convert an array to a list of nested objects - Eloquent Javascript 4.3

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, nested

I am looking at this exercise from the book Eloquent Javascript, Chapter 4 - [A List](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.3) for quite some time and I'm trying to understand how this particular function works:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}

console.log( arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Even after adding the `list` to the Watch window in the Debugger I can't clearly see the following:

1.  How does exactly the statement from list =  `{value: array[i], rest: list};` get appended to the `rest` property of the nested object, during each iteration?

Obviously, the dot `.rest` or bracket `['rest']` notation are not being used, and it is not being explicitly specified that during every following iteration we are referring to the property of the object or its later nested objects, so how does it get appended to the property of each next nested object.

I am expecting for every iteration to overwrite the contents of the `list` object, but this is not the case.

Comment: 1) Because it goes from back to front.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Can you please give me some detail of what you mean when you say it goes from back to front ?   Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: In each iteration, we create a new object containing the object from last iteration.**

In the line `list = {value: array[i], rest: list};`, the statement on the right of the `=` gets evaluated first. This means we create an object `{value: array[i], rest: list}`, containing the current values of `array[i]` and `list`. In the first iteration, `list` is `null` and `array[i]` is 20, so the object looks like this:

```
{value: 20, rest: null}
```

Only then do we assign this object to `list`.

In the next iteration, `list` isn’t `null` anymore, but `{value: 20, rest: null}`. So now, the object we create and assign to `list` looks like this:

```
{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

Comment: Thanks @jmb , this is the explanation and part of JS knowledge I was missing :   
 **In the line list = {value: array[i], rest: list};, the statement on the right of the = gets evaluated first.** Further reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence also helped.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to explain a little here. Let me know if something is unclear

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  // declare a empty variable to use is as a list
  let list = null;

  // Now iterate from the last element to the first. Example [10, 20]
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // iteration 1: i = 1 
    // we assign to list...
    list = {
        //the value of the current element
        value: array[i], // value = 20
        // the current list value before current assign
        rest: list // rest = null
    };
    // now it is assigned. list = {value: 20, rest: null}

    // ....

    // iteration 2: i = 0
    // we assign to list...
    list = {
        //the value of the current element
        value: array[i], // value = 10
        // the current list value before current assign
        rest: list // rest = {value: 20, rest: null}
    };
    // now it is assigned. list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Yes, I get it now, the assignment is done from the rigth to the left in this part: `list = {value: array[i], rest: list};`, so the value of `list` from outside of the loop gets assigned to the `rest : list` and than the entire thing gets assigned back to the `rest`